# C# UWP Converting from System.IO.Stream to Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType

Tags: c#, stream, uwp, clone, random-access

so I am trying to get IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType but cant, because I get exception:

```
"This IRandomAccessStream does not support the CloneStream method because it requires cloning and this stream does not support cloning."
```

And this happens on last line of the following code:

```
PixelDataProvider pix = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                transform,
                ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,
                ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
byte[] pixels = pix.DetachPixelData();

Stream pixStream = cropBmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
pixStream.Write(pixels, 0, (int)(width * height * 4));
IRandomAccessStream iStream= pixStream.AsRandomAccessStream(); //dafaq with streams
RandomAccessStreamReference iReferenceStream= RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(iStream);
IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType newStream = await iReferenceStream.OpenReadAsync();
```

Is there any workaround or something?

**Edit 1**

I have also tried this way, still doesn't work. (But now I get null not that Clone failed)

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await ras.WriteAsync(pixels.AsBuffer());
RandomAccessStreamReference iReferenceStream = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(ras);
IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType newStream = await iReferenceStream.OpenReadAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it seems you have used [`BitmapDecoder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder). The `BitmapDecoder` provides read access to bitmap container data as well as data from the first frame.

We should be able to create a new `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` for the encoder to write to and call [`BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder#Windows_Graphics_Imaging_BitmapEncoder_CreateForTranscodingAsync_Windows_Storage_Streams_IRandomAccessStream_Windows_Graphics_Imaging_BitmapDecoder_), passing in the in-memory stream and the decoder object.

For example:

```
Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream random = await Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/sunset.jpg")).OpenReadAsync();
Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
Windows.Graphics.Imaging.PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
byte[] buffer = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
InMemoryRandomAccessStream inMemoryRandomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(inMemoryRandomAccessStream, decoder);
encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 320;
encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 240;
await encoder.FlushAsync();
inMemoryRandomAccessStream.Seek(0);
random.Seek(0);
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
RandomAccessStreamReference iReferenceStream = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(inMemoryRandomAccessStream);
IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType newStream = await iReferenceStream.OpenReadAsync();
bitmapImage.SetSource(newStream);
MyImage.Source = bitmapImage;
```